# Dynamically update a Bar Chart by user selecting checkboxes in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a horizontal bar chart where one of the bars on the chart needs to be dynamic based on a user selection of checkboxes in a google sheet. I can get this to work with one checkbox "=IF(C5=TRUE,D5+100,100)" but not sure how to get to work when multiple check boxes are selected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwBrn.png)

I have a "Base UPH" of 100 and just need to add the values in the "Multiplier" column if the checkbox(s) are TRUE. The idea is that the user could select one or all of the checkboxes and see how the "C-Dynamic" would be improved.

Any tips, much appreciated Thanks!

Able to get to work, but only for a single checkbox with this formula: =IF(C5=TRUE,D5+100,100)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with SUMIF, like this:

> `=100+SUMIF(C5:C8,TRUE,D5:D8)`